# ¿ Cómo obtener la data de un boton que se encuentre en cualquier td de su misma fila?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Quiero obtener el valor del atributo data que se encuentra en un boton que a su ves se encuentra dentro de un td, al hacer click en cualquier td de la misma fila.

```html
<!-- Codigo del controlador-->

public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->Clase_model->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no   = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $clas) {
            $no++;
            $row   = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $clas->nClase;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<center><button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-teal waves-effect" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="edit_person(' . "'" . $clas->idClase . "'" . ')" data="$clas->idClase"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Editar</button>   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-red waves-effect" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_person(' . "'" . $clas->idClase . "'" . ')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Eliminar</button></center>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw"            => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal"    => $this->Clase_model->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->Clase_model->count_filtered(),
            "data"            => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    
    
    
<!-- Codigo HTML -->

<div class="body">
       <table id="table" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" style="min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; width: 1000px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th  style="width: 10%;">ITEM</th>
            <th style="width: 300px;">CLASE</th>
             <?php if ($permisosfuncion->opciones == 1): ?>
            <th style="width:200px; " align="center">OPCION</th>
              <?php endif?>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides es muy sencillo.  Algo asi:

```js
$("#table td").on("click", function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent();
  var data = tr.find('button').attr("data");
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>Test</td><td><button data="1">boton</button></td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td><td><button data="2">boton</button></td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td><td><button data="3">boton</button></td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con **jQuery** y el evento **click** asignamos a la *nueva variable* **data** el padre del elemento y después buscamos el atributo **data** del elemento **button** a encontrar.

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var data = $(this).parent().find('button').attr('data');
  console.log(data);
});
```